# how can I synchronise two transactions of two different projects?

Tags: java, database, transactions, jta

I have a java project and from this project i call web service request. Within the request I execute database update queries, and after that, in my local application I execute other update queries.

But I have a problem: if there is any update problem or exception handling in local (second) update, I want to rollback the transaction which is executed in web service request. Briefly, to synchronise, two transactions of the two different application. How can I do it?

I think, JTA could be solution. But I could not find any structure or example or anything exactly which I can apply to my projects.

Comment: You need to make the two transactions in the same application.

Comment: the projects are in the different servers. Isnt there any possible way to synchronise the transactions between two projects?

Comment: Anything is possible, but the simplest solution is to move one of the transactions so it is in the same process.  Unless you are keen to re-write portions of JTA and support that.  Getting distributed transactions right is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

A transaction in this case is a logic unit of steps to transform a database from one state to another. You want to do this with two databases, which results in usage of a distributed database management system. 
Possible solutions:

- Rework the dependency B -> A
- Merge the databases into one
- Use one of the existing distributed database management system
- Work with nested transactions: start T(A), start T(B), commit T(B), commit T(A)